# I have an error when I append enemies to my list of enemies. Odd lines are being drawn. Please Check my Code

Tags: python

I am working on a project for school, Space Invaders in Python following Tokyo EdTech's tutorial Video 6.
I have gotten to the point where I have added my enemies to the list and I am trying to move all of my enemies at the same time. Instead of moving at all, black lines are being drawn and arrows are coming off them. These lines are moving but the enemies won't move at all.

Here is my code:

```
#Space Invaders – Part 1
#Set up the Screen 
import turtle
import os
import math
import random

#Set up the screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("#2a363b")
wn.title("Space Invaders")

#Draw border
border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0) #O is the fastest
border_pen.color("#f8b195")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(3)
for side in  range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600) #fd is forward
    border_pen.lt(90) #lt is left
border_pen.hideturtle()

#Create the player turtle
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("#bbb5f1")
player.shape("triangle")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0,-250)
player.setheading(90)

playerspeed = 15

#Choose the number of enemies
number_of_enemies = 5
#Create an empty list of enemies
enemies = [] #DEFINING A LIST - the only thing that tells python that you're defining a list 
is square brackets

#add enemies to list
for i in range(number_of_enemies):
    #Create the enemy
    enemies.append(turtle.Turtle())

for enemy in enemies:
    enemy = turtle.Turtle()
    enemy.color("#bbb5f1")
    enemy.shape("circle")
    enemy.penup()
    enemy.speed(0)
    x = random.randint(-200, 200)
    y = random.randint(100, 250)
    enemy.setposition(x, y)


enemyspeed = 2


#Create the player's bullet
bullet = turtle.Turtle()
bullet.color("#f8b195")
bullet.shape("triangle")
bullet.penup()
bullet.speed(0)
bullet.setheading(90)
bullet.shapesize(0.5, 0.5)
bullet.hideturtle()


bulletspeed = 20

#Define Bullet State
#Ready = ready to fire
#Fire - bullet is firing
bulletstate = "ready"

    #Interactive Player Mode
def move_left(): #move the player left
    x = player.xcor() #cor stands for coordinate
    x -= playerspeed # x = x - playerspeed
    if x < -280:
        x = -280
player.setx(x)

def move_right ():
    x = player.xcor()
    x += playerspeed #instead of a - use a +
    if x > 280:
    x = 280
    player.setx(x)

def fire_bullet():
    #Declare bulletstate as a golabl if it needs changed
    global bulletstate #function "bulletstate" is defined outside the Main Loop therfore it is 
a global function
    if bulletstate == "ready":
         bulletstate = "fire"
    
    #Move Bullet to just above player
    x = player.xcor()
    y = player.ycor() +10
    bullet.setposition(x,y)
    bullet.showturtle()

def isCollision(t1, t2): #t = turtle
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(t1.xcor() - t2.xcor(), 2)+math.pow(t1.ycor() - t2.ycor(), 
2))#pow = power #sqrt = square root
    if distance < 15:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
#Create keyboard bindings
turtle.listen() 
turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left") #left function
turtle.onkey(move_right, "Right") #right function
turtle.onkey(fire_bullet, "space") #space function

#Main Game Loop
while True:

    for enemy in enemies:
    #Move the enemy
    x = enemy.xcor()
    x += enemyspeed
    enemy.setx(x)

    #Move the enemy back and down
    if enemy.xcor() > 280: #Move right
        y = enemy.ycor()
        y -= 40
        enemyspeed *= -1
        enemy.sety(y)
        
    if enemy.xcor() < -280: #Move left
        y = enemy.ycor()
        y -= 40
        enemyspeed *= -1
        enemy.sety(y)

#Move the bullet
if bulletstate == "fire":
    y = bullet.ycor()
    y += bulletspeed
    bullet.sety(y)
#Check to see if the bullet has gone to the top
if bullet.ycor() > 275:
    bullet.hideturtle()
    bulletstate = "ready"

#Check for a collision between the bullet and the enemy
if isCollision(bullet, enemy):
    #Reset the bullet
    bullet.hideturtle
    bulletstate = "ready"
    bullet.setposition(0, -400)
    #Reset the enemy
    enemy.setposition(-200, 250)

if isCollision(player, enemy):
    player.hideturtle()
    enemy.hideturtle()
    print ("Game Over")
    break

delay = raw_input("Press to finish.")
```

There previously was errors about "coords" but since moving the location of playerspeed and now there aren't any errors but he program is still now working.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the prog, and I see that there's a lot of turtles moving.
Keep in mind that drawing something at the turtle's pos won't move it when the turtle moves — the problem probably comes from this, from the ennemy turtles. You should verify and possibly modify your ennemy drawing code.

Probably, the error is in

```
for i in range(number_of_enemies):
    #Create the enemy
    enemies.append(turtle.Turtle())

for enemy in enemies:
    enemy = turtle.Turtle()
    enemy.color("#bbb5f1")
```

I think you should remove `enemy = turtle.Turtle()` because it's useless, as it changes an item of the list `enemies` from a `turtle.Turtle()` to a `turtle.Turtle()`. I don't know if it would work, but it may.

Comment: I have verified my code by checking it against the video and with my peers, I am certain that I have kept it word for word, but I don't know how I could modify my enemy drawing code, please could you help?